# Filtering attributes not working Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a users class that has several has_many associations.  I have a net pay page that will show each user and their associations.  I want to be able to filter to only show the associations for the month/year selected and what I currently have does not seem to work.

User Controller

```
 def net_pay
    @users = User.all.order(driver_id: :asc)
    @users.each do |user|
      search_date(user)
    end
 end

def show
  if params[:month_select]
    search_date(@user)
    total_deductions
  else
    @trips
  end
end

def search_date(user)
  @trips = user.trips.month_year(params[:month_select],params[:year_select])
  @advances = user.advances.month_year(params[:month_select],params[:year_select])
  @prorates = user.prorates.month_year(params[:month_select],params[:year_select])
  @icbcs = user.icbcs.month_year(params[:month_select],params[:year_select])
  @dentals = user.dentals.month_year(params[:month_select],params[:year_select])
  @others = user.others.month_year(params[:month_select],params[:year_select])
  @admin_expenses = user.admin_expenses.month_year(params[:month_select],params[:year_select])
end
```

The search works for the individual user, but when I need to iterate over all of the users to get just the month/year for each it does not save.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The iteration will overwrite the instance variables each time it loops over the users.

You could try passing in the `month` and `year` as instance variables to the view and then calling `user.trips.month_year(@month, @year)` in your iteration over `@users`. Or you could create an object which takes the parameters of user, month, and year and returns the values you expect. `@net_pay_users = @users.map { |user| UserNetPayBuilder.new(user, params[:month_select], params[:year_select]) }` and then iterate over `@net_pay_users` in your view.

```
def initialize(user, month, year)
  self.user = user
  ...
end

def trips
  user.trips.month_year(month, year)
end
```

You could further refactor the builder to accept a group of users and return a collection of useful objects to you instead of using the `map` inside the controller.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, you are a life saver!